# Add a new column to hive table with given criteria

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have got a Hive Table named Data which is partitioned on daily date, in which I have 3 columns: `name`,`sex`,`city`,`age`.

Now I want to add another column named `AgeRange` to this existing Hive table in which the values will be dependent based on the data of column `Age`.

If `Age < 18`, value will be `0`. If `Age >= 18 and <= 23`, value will be `1`, else value will be `2`.

How can I write the query for this? This needs to be done for the past data i.e date till yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first add a column and then `update` (hopefully your Hive supports it) all records with `CASE` statement.

```
ALTER TABLE Data ADD COLUMNS (AgeRange Varchar);

UPDATE Data  SET AgeRange  = ( CASE WHEN Age < 18 THEN 0 
                                    WHEN Age >= 18 and <= 23 THEN 1
                                    ELSE 2 END );
```

Answer (score 1):

If your Hive does not support `Update` or the table is huge, then create new table with additional column and insert overwrite from old table:

```
insert overwrite table new_table
select 
      name,
      sex,
      city,
      age,
      case when Age < 18                then 0 
           when Age >= 18 and Age <= 23 then 1
           else                              2 
       end AgeRange
  from old_table;
```

then drop old table and rename new table.